# FirebaseRemoteConfig condition on app version

Tags: firebase-remote-config

Do you know how FirebaseRemoteConfig works on app update ?
If a value depends on a version condition (i.e. = v1.0), once the user update the app, the value should be considered stale and the condition is not valid anymore.

How can I force the app to retrieve the new value after an app update, if the remoteConfig cache is not stale yet ?

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseRemoteConfig will fetch the latest config according to inverval you specified.

If a value depends on a `app version` condition, the config value will be updated immediately according to `app version`.

I don't recommend but you may **force** remote config to fetch after a short interval.

```kotlin
/* cache live time forced to 10 seconds */
FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().fetch(10) 
// must be activated after fetch
```